# Semiconductor doping and conductivity

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Why is the conductivity of Si dopped with P and As much bigger than the conductivity of Si dopped with In and P?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean doped with (P,As) vs (P,In), that is both together.  And I assume you are comparing similar concentrations.

In that case, note that both P and As are donors, so both will add carriers to the conduction band.  In contrast, In is an acceptor, so it will counteract the P resulting in a lower carrier concentration (compensation).